# Tor 7.0.1 App Crashes when I try to open it

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, help

I have Windows 7 Service pack 1 and my browser is opera.

I downloaded Tor but on trying to connect I got the following:

```
Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   APPCRASH
  Application Name: firefox.exe
  Application Version:  52.2.0.6242
  Application Timestamp:    00000000
  Fault Module Name:    KERNELBASE.dll
  Fault Module Version: 6.1.7601.23796
  Fault Module Timestamp:   59028e59
  Exception Code:   c06d007f
  Exception Offset: 0000c54f
  OS Version:   6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
  Locale ID:    2057
  Additional Information 1: 0a9e
  Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Additional Information 3: 0a9e
  Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789

Read our privacy statement online:
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=104288&clcid=0x0409

If the online privacy statement is not available, please read our privacy statement offline:
  C:\Windows\system32\en-US\erofflps.txt
```

Comment: I get exactly the same since the update!! also pages are not displaying correctly, its like it reverted to a basic view type option on mine!"

Comment: I did have the same problem.
Update to 7.01 didn't fix the problem.
Installing old version 6.5 did.
I will wait for a new update > 7.01.

Comment: Restart Windows into Safe Mode with Networking and try launching it.