# TBB will not lauch, Firefox Failure

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, firefox

from the Application Log: Snip>>>

Faulting application name: firefox.exe, version: 52.2.0.6242, time stamp: 0x00000000

Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 10.0.15063.296, time stamp: 0x28e9cf15

Exception code: 0xc06d007f

<<

Win 10, HP Pavillion, i5

I have re-installed tor Browser with no succes. Any help regarding the error above greatly appreciated.

Also getting a bunch of active Directory issues. I do not us AD!! This is strictly a home computer.

Any connection?

Comment: Duplicate of https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/15034/tor-7-0-1-app-crashes-when-i-try-to-open-it